# UISearch con MVP

Tags: swift, xcode

tengo una duda acerca de esta arquitectura y es la siguiente:
Si la lógica ha de estar en el Presenter , pero en el caso de los filtros de búsqueda por ejemplo , es recomendable implementar la lógica de `array.filter {}` dentro del mismo viewcontroller o es mejor que se llame al Presenter y que se encargue el ?

Comment: los datos deberían estar en el presenter y estar pasándole desde la vista lo que se busca y desde el presenter devolviendo lo que hay que mostrar

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta